# IE11 causing layout issues with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I, like many others, am having trouble getting my flexbox page layout to work in IE11. My code validates just fine on the W3C Validator, and I added all the necessary prefixes. I read through the common issues with flexbox in IE11 as well, but couldn't seem to figure out where exactly the issue is for me or how to fix it.

[How the homepage supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkhPI.jpg)

[How another section is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyb0J.jpg)

[How the homepage looks in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zWn9.jpg)

[How the other section looks in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH04i.jpg)

And a link to my code (minus the parts that are working properly): https://jsfiddle.net/f09skq5w/

This is the CSS for the sections of the page, from what I read there can be issues with the min-height but I tried a few workarounds and none of the seemed to do the trick:

```
section {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding: 60px 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

And then the code for the #projects section that you can see in the 2nd and 4th image.

```
#projects .grid li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30%;
      flex-basis: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

#projects .thumbnail-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 235px;
  padding: 0 30px 25px;
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some pointers... add `left: 0` to `.home-content`. Add `width: 100%` to `.project-list`. Remove `flex-basis` property from `.about-caption`. ... let me know if it helps

Comment: One thing you should keep in mind is that [**absolutely positioned children of a flex container do not participate in flex layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items). You can either use CSS positioning properties to center your content, or remove the absolute positioning and let flex properties do their work.